# Cannot validate argument on parameter 'path' powershel

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I've been trying to add users from a csv to different OU. I don't know why I get an error with the OU path, saying that the path parameter is empty when the OU is in the csv. Please help.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
#$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "Pass123" -AsPlainText -Force
$usuarios=Import-Csv C:\Usuarios2.csv
foreach ($usuario in $usuarios)
{
  $codigo = $usuario.Código
  $nombre = $usuario.Nombre
  $apellido = $usuario.Apellido
  $facultad = $usuario.Facultad
  $carrera = $usuario.Carrera
  $OUpath = $usuario."Organizational Unit"
  #New-ADUser -Name "$nombre $apellido" -GivenName $nombre -Surname $apellido -UserPrincipalName $codigo -Path "$OUpath" -AccountPassword $password -ChangePasswordAtLogon $True -Enabled $True   
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide the error you are receiving in the question body as well as an excerpt of the csv? A couple rows should suffice. I can tell you you don't need to have the double-quotes around `$OUpath` on your `New-ADUser` command.

Comment: the error is "Cannot validate argument on parameter 'path'  " and I can't figure out what I did wrong. When I tell it to print the usernames it does but it won't print the OUpath .

Comment: Can you please paste or screenshot the first row of the csv with headers into the question body? Specifically looking at the "Organizational Unit" column.

Comment: https://ibb.co/ZNvx6YJ this is the excel page and i export it as a csv file

Comment: There is a space character in `OU= FIA` (right behind the `=`) that shouldn't be there. Also your encoding seems wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information you provided with the error and the screenshot of the csv you are iterating over, it looks to me like when you iterate, you are assigning `$OUpath` to the value contained in `$usuario."Organizational Unit"`.

However, in the csv, the title of that column is actually "OU", so you should the using:

```
$OUpath = $usuario.OU
```

Comment: I've changed it to OU and it still won't recognize it, it still says "Cannot validate argument on parameter 'path' "

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your ou path is not properly quoted and therefore it's only pulling the first section of the distinguished name. Check this example for clarity.

```
$usuarios = @'
Código,Nombre,Apellido,Facultad,Carrera,OU
testupn,first,last,not used in command,also not used,OU=Some OU,DC=Domain,DC=COM
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv
```

Now let's look at the OU property.

```
$usuarios.ou

OU=Some OU
```

If this is the case you can either save it with a custom delimiter or quote the OU path.

```
$usuarios = @'
Código,Nombre,Apellido,Facultad,Carrera,OU
testupn,first,last,not used in command,also not used,"OU=Some OU,DC=Domain,DC=COM"
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv

$usuarios.ou

OU=Some OU,DC=Domain,DC=COM
```

or

```
$usuarios = @'
Código;Nombre;Apellido;Facultad;Carrera;OU
testupn;first;last;not used in command;also not used;OU=Some OU,DC=Domain,DC=COM
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ';'

$usuarios.ou

OU=Some OU,DC=Domain,DC=COM
```

Comment: I tried doing that it still says that the parameter "path" is null or empty